# How to compile all cpp files in multiple sub directories?

Tags: c++, macos, makefile

So currently, I have a makefile setup where I compile all the cpp files in a single directory, `src`. It is structured as follows

```
CCPP = g++
CPPFLAGS =  -std=c++11
CPPLINK = -lstdc++
INC_DIR = include

CPP_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES := $(addprefix lib/,$(notdir $(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)))
LD_FLAGS :=
CC_FLAGS := -c $(CPPFLAGS) -Wall -I$(INC_DIR)

bin/Xenon: $(OBJ_FILES) ; $(CCPP) $(LD_FLAGS) -o $@ $^

lib/%.o: src/%.cpp ; $(CCPP) $(CC_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

However, although this works, I want to divide src into multiple sub directories of cpp files.

How would I make this solution work for any number of sub directories under a single `src` folder?

Note: Here `bin/Xenon` is a CLI application executable with a main method, and INC_DIR is where all my header files are. This is also on OSX, not windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy part is

```
CPP_FILES := $(wildcard src/*/*.cpp)   # if all are in subdirectories
CPP_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp src/*/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst src/%,lib/%,$(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o))
```

You don't want `$(notdir)` if you might have the same file name in multiple directories.

You'll also have to worry about making the corresponding subdirectories of `lib`.  The simplest thing to do might be to make sure each exists when writing to it:

```
lib/%.o: src/%.cpp
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CCPP) $(CC_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: When i do this i get an error `make: *** No rule to make target `lib/src/main/Main.o', needed by `bin/Xenon'.  Stop.` Every cpp is under a sub dir

Comment: Works like a charm now! Thanks!